# How to improve qscrollarea performance with large number of images?

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I'm trying to implement a document/image viewer using qscrollarea. I found qscrollarea performing slow when loading files with many pages. For a document with about 1.3k pages, it took about half a minute to finish loading.

The main loading procedure is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DOC_COUNT; ++i) {
  QLabel *label = new QLabel();
  label->setPixmap(IMAGE);
  qvboxlayout_->addWidget(label);
  QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
```

I know android has a mechanism that the system automatically inflates, recycles and reuses views. Does qt has such a mechanism?

Comment: Your problem is in loading all these images ahead of time. Don't do that. Load them on-demand. You'll have to customize the `QLabel` a bit to achieve that, or make your own widget.

Comment: @KubaOber So how to "Load them on-demand"? Can you show me some clues?

Comment: You can perform the loading after the first time the label has to paint itself: monitor when the label gets the repaint event, and only load and set the image on it then. You'll need to know the sizes of each image a-priori, though, so that the labels have correct sizes but no contents.

Comment: @KubaOber It seems that all QLabels will repaint itself on initilization. I tried to use isVisible() or visibleRegion() to determine whether it is out of visible region, however, the two functions always report itself as visible.

Comment: IIRC, they will only repaint if they have an incorrect size, otherwise they won't be visible and won't repaint. Otherwise, use a `QGraphicsScene` and add images to it.

Comment: @KubaOber , thanks! I finally solved this problem by removing all qlabels and draw directly on the QScrollArea.

Answer (score 2):

Yours is typical case where you'd use model-view programming. Subclass `QAbstractListModel` and use QListView to achieve your goals. Adding widgets directly to `QScrollArea` or for that matter painting directly on `QScrollArea` are memory intensive and very bad ideas.

The [Item Views Puzzle Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-puzzle-example.html) is almost exactly what you need.